# Name of a place at the end of a long journey

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Whats a word for a PLACE for weary travelers, a PLACE you reach after a long, arduous journey.

Another name the for Destination, that really implies difficulty reaching it

Comment: You could say "he has completed his metaphorical Ithaca" or "My Odysseus adventure has now ended"; both with reference to Homer's epic poem *Odyssey*. [Read about it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey) or [Read it here](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1727)

Comment: Sometimes the end of such a trip is one's *home*.

Answer (score 3):

They reached their final goal, or safe haven, or journey's end (as per nicole). Not sure there is one word or short phrase in English - that conveys all the meaning you require (reaching an end point after a long or arduous journey).

Comment: +1 for haven.  It conveys a safe place.

Answer (score 2):

How about "journey's end", or "terminus"?

Answer (score 1):

*Refuge* accommodates the notion of a place of safety that one travels to after completing a journey of some type.